# add auto-increment to db without changing current IDs - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id   |  name 
--------------
1    | John
2    | Mary
.
.
.
NULL | Brian
NULL | Jacob
```

I meant to make id an AUTO INCREMENT row, but I guess I did not b/c when I added new names `Brian, Jacob`, it didn't automatically add incremented id values. I am wondering if there is a way to add those values to replace NULL, without changing any of the id's above it.

Comment: There is one approach. Copy over the existing table to a `temp` table, drop the current table and re-create it (with the correct table structure) and then copy the values back over from `temp`.

Comment: You can set AUTO_INCREMENT = 1. 
reset you primary key seeds to 1
for reference : https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/auto_increment_reset.php

Answer (score 2):

Demo:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id int, name text);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable values
    -> (1, 'John'),
    -> (2, 'Mary'),
    -> (NULL, 'Brian'),
    -> (NULL, 'Jacob');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table mytable modify column id int auto_increment, add primary key (id);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | Mary  |
|  3 | Brian |
|  4 | Jacob |
+----+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Conclusion: Yes.

You do need `id` to be the first column in a key (I used PRIMARY KEY here). MySQL's InnoDB storage engine won't let a column be auto-increment unless it's the leftmost column in some key (that is, any index will suffice).

Comment: I get a ```Query 1 ERROR: Out of range value for column 'columns' at row 167``` when I run that. It's worth mentioning that the current ID's aren't perfect increments, it goes like 1,3,4,6,7,...,with the largest id value being 23,899. I tried adding a ```auto_increment = 23,900``` but doesn't work either

Comment: Looks like it's this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98211 Please upgrade to 8.0.21 or later, the bug is reportedly fixed in that version.